# Node - multipart/form-data uploading file but no data

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload

I've been trying to solve this for a few days now. I'm trying to do file upload and POST data in the same request. I've done this in PHP but now I want to do this in Node.js. I though it may be something with the headers or server setup but nothing is working.

How I got here: I started with the file upload using `busboy` and it works perfect. Used a `Content-Type: Multipart/form-data` with `form-data` body and it works fine:

```
app.post('/api/v1/files/test', function (req, res, next) {
  var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

  // Listen for event when Busboy finds a file to stream.
  busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    console.log(filename);
  });

  req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

This returns the filename in the console and works.

The next step was adding in additional information which is common. The request looks like this:
[image]

(Ignore the fact I have `apiKey` in body. That's the next thing I'm fixing.)

If I add a `console.log(req.body);`, it will return `{}`. **What am I missing? Why is the body empty? I've gone through `req` and cannot find any instance of my key.**

The server setup file looks like this:

```
... requires ...
// App
const app = express();

// File related
app.use(busboy());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // maybe screwing it up?
... then path setup, and listen ...
```

If you still don't understand what I'm trying to do:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="apiKey" />
   <input type="file" name="file" />
   <button type="submit>Done</button>
</form>
```

This is what it would look like in PHP:

```
<?php
   $apiKey = $_POST['apiKey'];
   $file = $_POST['files']['file'];
?>
```

Comment: Did you take a look at Multer: https://github.com/expressjs/multer, it's pretty simple and straight to the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using busboy, try installing [busboy-body-parser](https://github.com/lennym/busboy-body-parser), then use:

```
const busboyBodyParser = require('busboy-body-parser');

...

// Required to parse multipart/form-data for busboy
app.use(busboyBodyParser());
```

Comment: this does solve my issue with the blank body but it doesn't allow the file to upload any more. Any ideas on how to use this and still do file upload?

Comment: I take it back, this worked perfectly. I just checked `req.files` and it exists. This is the solution. Thanks for your help.